# Why the solution of $u+\lambda u' = f$ is $u(x)=Lf(x)+ae^{x/\lambda}$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Why is the general solution of $u+\lambda u' = f$ , for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and $\lambda>0$ (fixed)  $u(x)=Lf(x)+ae^{x/\lambda}$; $a \in \mathbb{R}?$ Here
$$Lf(x) = \dfrac{1}{\lambda}\int_{-\infty}^{x}e^{\frac{s-x}{\lambda}}f(s)\,ds.$$

I'm trying to put this general solution into the equation, but I can't see that it satisfies the solution
$$ \dfrac{1}{\lambda}\int_{-\infty}^{x}e^{\frac{s-x}{\lambda}}f(s)\,ds + ae^{x/\lambda} +\lambda \left( \dfrac{d}{dx}\dfrac{1}{\lambda}\int_{-\infty}^{x}e^{\frac{s-x}{\lambda}}f(s)\,ds +\dfrac{a}{\lambda}e^{x/\lambda}  \right)  = f.$$
Any tips?

Comment: Is the simpler method of integrating factors not applicable? Seems like it should be at first glance

Comment: Isn't there a sign error somewhere? Either there should be a minus sign in the differential equation or it should be $ae^{-x/\lambda}.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The derivative on the RHS of where you're plugging things in is a bit tricky: $x$ appears both in the upper limit of the derivative as well as in the integrand. When that happens, you must invoke the Leibniz Rule:
$$\frac{d}{dx}\int_{a(x)}^{b(x)}f(x,t)\,dt
=f(x,b(x))\,b'(x)-f(x,a(x))\,a'(x)+\int_{a(x)}^{b(x)}\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\,f(x,t)\,dt.$$
In your case, you get
$$\frac{d}{dx}\int_{-\infty}^xe^{(s-x)/\lambda}f(s)\,ds
=f(x)-\frac{1}{\lambda}\int_{-\infty}^xe^{(s-x)/\lambda}f(s)\,ds.$$
This explains how the integrals cancel. I agree, though, with md2perpe: $u$ should be $u(x)=Lf(x)+ae^{-x/\lambda},$ so that you pick up a minus sign upon differentiation and the exponentials will also cancel out.

Comment: Thanks for the help, i really thought i was missing the integral, so i couldn't cancel the exponential term, this problem appears in a proposition in the Brezis Cazenave book of evolution equations.

Comment: You're welcome! Glad I could be of help.